# Monitoring node.js axios requests with prometheus

Tags: node.js, axios, metrics, prometheus

I have node.js microservice with axios requests to external api, and I need monitor them with prometheus. As I see, prometheus is made to monitor express requests:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
  const responseTimeInMs = Date.now() - res.locals.startEpoch;

  httpRequestDurationMs
      .labels(req.method, req.route.path, res.statusCode)
      .observe(responseTimeInMs);

  next();
});
```

But I found no way to use it with axios (for example):

```
function getData() {
  return axios.get(url)
    .then (res) => {
      [should put metrics somewhere here]
    }
}
```

Hope someone could help with this.

Comment: try this.
https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-performance-monitoring-with-prometheus/

Comment: I've already used it, but there's only express in the example. I've described it in the first part of my question, it's not the thing I need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [prom-client](https://github.com/siimon/prom-client) documentation - you can start a timer and call the return method on finish:

```
const end = gauge.startTimer();
xhrRequest(function(err, res) {
  end(); // Sets value to xhrRequests duration in seconds
});
```

Use it with gauge, histogram, summary or any other object...